# iOS9 how to know if I'm leaking memory at runtime?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, profiling, ios9, xcode7

I'm building an app for an external camera, attached via lightning connector, so I cannot debug/profile the app with XCode/Instruments while the camera is attached. **Is there a way for me to understand if my app is leaking memory at runtime?** Or maybe see the amount of memory my app is using?

Answer (score 1):

If you put log statements in your app that return information about memory usage, you can check the system logs for possible memory leaks after running through your app.

> This can only be done on a mac:
>
> - Connect your device to a Mac
> - Open Xcode, go to Window->Devices in the title bar
> - Click on your device from the sidebar
> - Click 'View Device Logs'

Reference: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/165100/how-to-read-iphone-system-logs

Also see: https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/